# The sample program packaging of pljava cannot find maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, pljava

https://tada.github.io/pljava/use/hello.html

I want to package a jar according to the sample program, but pljava-api cannot be found in maven. What is the reason or from which repository can I download dependency?

I went to look for it in the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 warehouse and found that I couldn't find it. However, the pljava documentation did not specify which warehouse I should download the dependencies from. I tried the maven central warehouse and the Alibaba Cloud maven warehouse. , the dependency of this pljava cannot be found, what should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.